# Value of type 'UNNotificationSettings' has no member 'timeSensitiveSetting' - UrbanAirship pod prevent from build to succeed after pod update

Tags: swift, xcode, urbanairship.com

Using Xcode 13.
after updating my pods i cannot compile my project because the UrbanAirship pod show some error:

```
Value of type 'UNNotificationSettings' has no member 'timeSensitiveSetting'
```

and

```
Value of type 'UNNotificationSettings' has no member 'scheduledDeliverySetting'
```

for lines:

```
#if !os(tvOS) && !targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)

if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    if notificationSettings.timeSensitiveSetting == .enabled {
         authorizedSettings.insert(.timeSensitive)
    }
                
    if notificationSettings.scheduledDeliverySetting == .enabled {
         authorizedSettings.insert(.scheduledDelivery)
    }
}

#endif
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using Xcode 13?

Comment: @DávidPásztor yes man

Comment: Hi @AsiGivati, i am also facing the same issue. Did you found any solution for it. If yes can you please post your answer below. It may be helpful to others as well.

Comment: Hi @Madhu, sorry but no. as you can see, there is no answer here yet =\